# Could you check my sql select statement and help to improve it

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Task: Calculate for each faculties average and max age of students and select faculties where maximum age more then 23.
Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE GROUP (
    faculty varchar2(255)  NOT NULL,
    N_group integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT GROUP_pk PRIMARY KEY (N_group)
);
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    N_student integer  NOT NULL,
    surname varchar2(255)  NOT NULL,
    birthdate integer  NOT NULL,
    N_group integer  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT STUDENT_pk PRIMARY KEY (N_student)
) ;
ALTER TABLE STUDENT ADD CONSTRAINT Student_Group 
    FOREIGN KEY (N_group)
    REFERENCES GROUP (N_group)
    ;
```

My statement:

```
SELECT GROUP.FACULTY
         ,AVG(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-STUDENT.BIRTHDATE)
         ,MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-STUDENT.BIRTHDATE)
FROM GROUP 
     JOIN STUDENT USING(N_GROUP)
GROUP BY GROUP.FACULTY
```

But I can't write second part of task. I though `WHERE 'MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-STUDENT.BIRTHDATE) > 23'` to add is enough, but it's wrong statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: filtering on aggregate results is done with a "having" clause.  Not related to your question, but a field named birthdate that stores only the birth year is odd.  It also means that in some cases your ages will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan Bracuk!
There are 2 solutions at least:
1)

```
SELECT GROUP.FACULTY
         ,AVG(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-STUDENT.BIRTHDATE)
         ,MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-STUDENT.BIRTHDATE)
FROM GROUP 
     JOIN STUDENT USING(N_GROUP)
GROUP BY GROUP.FACULTY
HAVING MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-STUDENT.BIRTHDATE) > 23
```

2)

```
SELECT * (SELECT GROUP.FACULTY
         ,AVG(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-STUDENT.BIRTHDATE)
         ,MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-STUDENT.BIRTHDATE) AS MAX_AGE
FROM GROUP 
     JOIN STUDENT USING(N_GROUP)
GROUP BY GROUP.FACULTY) WHERE MAX_AGE > 23
```